# getMessage is not defined

Tags: javascript

Why does this:

```
function ConditionsTarifairesForm_required () { 
        this.a0 = new Array("dateDebutDeValiditeDuPlanDAffaires", getMessage('errors.required','Date de début'), new Function ("varName", "this.datePattern='yyyy/MM/dd';  return this[varName];"));
        this.a1 = new Array("dateFinDeValiditeDuPlanDAffaires", getMessage('errors.required','Date&nbsp;de&nbsp;fin'), new Function ("varName", "this.datePattern='yyyy/MM/dd';  return this[varName];"));
        this.a2 = new Array("tarifEnVigueur", getMessage('errors.required','Tarif en vigueur'), new Function ("varName", " return this[varName];"));
        this.a3 = new Array("dateDebutTarif", getMessage('errors.required','Date de début'), new Function ("varName", "this.datePattern='yyyy/MM/dd';  return this[varName];"));
        if(document.getElementsByName('delaiDePaiementFacture')[0].disabled == false) {
            this.a4 = new Array("delaiDePaiementFacture", getMessage('errors.required','Délai&nbsp;de&nbsp;paiement'), new Function ("varName", " return this[varName];"));
        }else {
            if(document.getElementsByName('delaiDePaiement.value')[0].selectedIndex == 7
            || document.getElementsByName('delaiDePaiement.value')[0].selectedIndex == 0) {
                this.a4 = new Array("delaiDePaiement", getMessage('errors.required','Délai&nbsp;de&nbsp;paiement'), new Function ("varName", " return this[varName];"));
            }
        }       
   }
```

produce this error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getMessage is not defined

Comment: Because you haven't defined what `getMessage` is... I would think someone with reputation this high would do better than this.

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory, don't you think?

Comment: I think the error message is self-explanatory: `getMessage` function is not defined. Check if all the scripts are included on the page

Answer (score 1):

I suppose because you have not declared your function `getMessage`.

Comment: i don't know where is getMessage is define

Comment: @Mercer if you don't know...how would we possibly know?

Comment: As I can see you use `getMessage` function as a second argument in your Array. That means that you should define this function in your code in order to use its logic.